# Can't resolve "no module named crypto error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

I am trying to use `crypto` package for AES encryption but when I try to run it is giving error

```
from Crypto import Random
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

However I have crypto installed on my system. I have googled this error someone said to uninstall it but when I do so it is giving below error

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall `'pycrypto'`. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Someone else told to create new envrironment variable.I am using this on `pycharm` and already created virtualenv and install `crypto` in this virtual env but still not runnying. Any help?

Comment: Are you importing from `Crypto` or `crypto`? Case matters.

Comment: i am using Crypto